# JSON API with Django Rest - 'included' attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am creating [JSON-API](http://jsonapi.org/) using Django-rest framework. I could structure the returned JSON object in the same way as JSON-API documentation specifies, except for "included" attribute. Is there any way to include multiple serialized objects of related-models?

For example

If I have two model classes

```
# Snippet Model
from django.db import models
class Snippet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='snippets')

# Comment Model
from django.db import models
class Comment(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='comments')
```

and I have the serializers for those two models:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     model = Snippet
     fields = ('id','created', 'title')

from rest_framework import serializers
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     model = Comment
     fields = ('id','created', 'title')
```

and I have User serializer

```
# User serializer
from .serializers import SnippetSerializer
from .serializers import CommentSerializer
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    included = serializers.SerilizerMethodField()
    class Meta: 
        model = User
        fields = ('id','included')

     def get_included(self, obj):
        included_objs = []
        request = self.context['request']

        # check if requested url has a query parameter "included" 
        query = request.QUERY_PARAMS['included'] if 'included' in  request.QUERY_PARAMS else None
        if query:
             queries = query.split(',')
             if 'included' in queries:
                  snippets = SnippetSerializer(many=True, read_only=True).data
                  comments = CommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True).data
                  included_objs.append(snippets)
                  included_objs.append(comments)
        return included_objs
```

and these code didn't give me what I needed.

The objective is that if requested url includes a query "included", then API will return a JSON object with CommentSerialized and SnippetSerialized objects related to user object under 'included' attribute.   The result should be something like this.

```
{
   "id" : 1,
   "included": [
       {'id': 2,'created': "20150729", "title":'snippet' },
       {'id': 2,'created': "20150730", "title":"comment" }, 
       {'id': 3,'created': "20150731", "title":"comment" }, 
   ] 
 }
```

It would be wonderful if someone can help me out here. Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to include the queryset in the SnippetSerializer and CommentSerializer object. You still might want to seperate out the seperate models however.

Comment: I might as well mention that there is a WIP [JSON API renderer for DRF](https://github.com/kevin-brown/drf-json-api) that you might be interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I would write a second serializer:

```
class IncludedUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      snippets = SnippetSerializer(source = 'snippet_set', many=True)
      comments = CommentSerializer(source = 'comment_set', many=True)

      class Meta:
          model=User
          fields = ('id','snippets', 'comments')
```

Then in your view override the get_serializer method

```
 def get_serializer(self):
     if self.query_params.get('included', None):
           return IncludedUserSerializer
     else:
           return UserSerializer
```

Comment: But this won't display serialized objects of snippets and comments under "included" attribute.

Answer (score 3):

The project [django-rest-framework-json-api](https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api/) recently implemented support for this behavior.

It's used like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    # PostSerializer NOT included directly on the serializer, ResourceRelatedField is 
    # specified as default
    posts = relations.ResourceRelatedField(
        source='post_set', many=True, read_only=True) 

    # specifies serializer to use when passing in the `include` param
    included_serializers = {
        'posts': PostSerializer,
    }
```

If I understand well, you already implemented part of the JSON-API specification by yourself, so I don't know if it's viable for you to switch things and use their project. But looking on how they implemented what you want may be of some help.
See [this](https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api/issues/256) and [this](https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api/pull/250), for example.